# Difference in use between "only" and "just" in these examples, what is the rule?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Sometimes it is clear to me that "only" and "just" can be used interchangeably, for example:

> It is **only/just** a few minutes away from the station.

> **Only/just** two students came to class on the day before Christmas.

And it is clear to me that sometimes "just" is the only option when it means "very recently".

But are there occasions when only "only" can be used? Is the rule that you use "only" when it is used as an adjective? For example, in the first sentence below I'm very sure we can't use "just":

> This is the **only** photograph I have of my great grandfather.

However for the following example is the only option also "only" or can I also use "just"?

> I went to the supermarket and there was **only** one cookie.

> I went to the supermarket and there was **just** one cookie.

Both sound Ok to me but perhaps the final example with "just" is incorrect? Or if not what are the rules around this please?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionaries?

Comment: Yes I've looked up lots of different examples of uses but the rules have not been clear. Or maybe there are no specific rules and each example works differently, as in my original post

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that "only" and "just" can generally be used interchangeably, but there are some cases where only "only" is appropriate. For example, when you're emphasizing exclusivity or singularity, "only" is the better choice. That's why in the sentence "This is the only photograph I have of my great grandfather," using "just" would not convey the same sense of exclusivity as "only" does.

As for your second example, both "only" and "just" work well and can be used interchangeably without changing the meaning of the sentence. While "only" often connotes exclusivity or limitation, and "just" emphasizes a small amount or a brief moment in time, there is overlap in their usage, and the decision between them should depend on the specific context and intended meaning of the sentence.

Moreover, generally speaking, "just" is more informal, and it most likely wouldn't fit in a formal context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one query: you say that in my example "just would not convey the same sense of exclusivity". But surely the sentence "This is the just photograph I have of my great grandfather" is simply incorrect rather than just conveying the wrong idea. Do you agree? I'm trying to figure out if a certain rule applies or if it's just a matter of each example being different

Comment: @JoR "This is the just photograph I have of my great grandfather" is grammatically incorrect. Therefore, it does not have any meaning. The word "just" in this sentence doesn't make sense. This is because "just" doesn't mean "singular".

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why "I went to the supermarket and there was just one cookie" would be correct while the example with "just photograph" would be incorrect, but I believe I understand now with the answer above

Answer (score 0):

> But are there occasions when only "only" can be used? Is the rule that you use "only" when it is used as an adjective?

Yes, that is correct, as most dictionaries will indicate. (That may be why you were asked in a comment whether you'd looked in a dictionary.) There certainly is an adjective "just", but it has a different meaning, so I'm not considering it here.

> However for the following example is the only option also "only" or can I also use "just"?

In that example, the word that you're asking about is an adverb, not an adjective. (The fact that it appears before the determiner "one" suggests that.) Therefore, either word can be used.

> Or if not what are the rules around this please?

You've already said it yourself: "Only" can be either an adjective or adverb, while "just" is solely an adverb. There is no specific rule; you just have to pay attention to parts of speech.

Finally, I'll just note that much more can be said about this subject. However, I'm limiting myself to the issues that you asked about.

Comment: thank you, understood!